# How to configure startup.cs based on solution configuration and not environment variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

One way of configuring startup.cs is to check the environment based on an environmental variable, and run the appropriate code within the Configure method:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    //app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

For the app I'm working on, I can't guarantee that I will have access to clients' machines to add the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environmental variable to make sure they're routed to the correct exception page. But I also don't want to keep having to remember to comment out certain code when I'm about to publish the project.

How can I instead get the project's configuration name to determine what code I want run?:

[image]

Here's some pseudocode of what I'd like to accomplish:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //I get the configuration name (could be "Debug", "Development", or "Release)
    //from the list in the photo
    string configurationName = GetConfigurationName();

    //I compare the name to determine what error page to show
    if (configurationName == "Debug" || configurationName == "Development")
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    //app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't make it work with the environment, you could use a [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/). When deploying your code to production, make sure you are compiling with RELEASE as solution configuration:

```
#if DEBUG
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
#elif RELEASE
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
#endif
```

You can find some nice examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if):

Comment: Thank you! This provides me the functionality I was looking for.